# Probability with multiple parts

Tags: probability

I was reading a cool probability question today and I couldn't quite get it.

The question:

Kevin is taking an exam with $k > 1$, numbered Part $1, 2, ..., k$. It is known that for $i = 1, 2, ..., k$, Part $i$ contains $i$ multiple choice questions, each of which has $i + 1$ answer choices. It is known that if he guesses randomly on every single question, the probability he gets exactly one question correct is equal to $10$ times the probability that she gets no questions correct. Compute the number of questions that are on the exam.

My solution:

I first tried thinking about how many total questions there were. There are obviously $1 + 2 + 3... + k$ questions which is $\frac{k(k + 1)}{2}$ total questions.

I then realized that was leading nowhere. I then tried calculating the probability that he gets exactly $1$ question correct.

Probability that he gets question $1$ correct) $\frac{1}{2}$

Probability that he gets question $1$ wrong then something from part $2$ correct) $\frac{2}{9}$

But this wasn't getting me anywhere since I didn't know what $k$ was.

I did know that the probability that he got everything wrong was $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{3}^2... * (\frac{1}{k + 1})^k$.

I don't know what to do with multiple parts. Maybe there's a way to simplify the problem?

But I didn't know what to do next and I am very confused. Someone please help me think about what I should do next. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it’s $10$ times and not anything else?

Comment: @Tavish yes I'm sure

Comment: @Tavish very interesting but I checked my key and there's actually an answer but no solution :(

Comment: @Iamaperson What is the answer? There is no need to hide this information!

Comment: @callculus it was 55

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the probability of getting every question wrong be $p$. Then $$p= \frac{1}{2} \cdot (\frac 23)^2 \cdot (\frac 34)^3 \cdots (\frac {k}{k+1} )^k $$

The probability of getting one question right in any part $i$ is $$\binom{i}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{i+1} \cdot \left( \frac{i}{i+1} \right)^{i-1} \times \frac{p}{\left(\frac{i}{i+1} \right)^i} =p$$ Therefore, the probability of getting exactly one question right is $$\sum_{i=1}^k p = kp =10 p \implies k=10$$

Comment: This is the correct answer for k! Then the answer is 1 + 2... + 10 = 55!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Cool, you’re welcome.